# Getting all the values from a entity reference field (Drupal 8)

Tags: theming, entities

I'm trying to figure how I can get all the values inside an entity reference field

As shown in this image, I have an entity field called Target Participants(field_program_participants) with multiple values. 
[image]

I have tried to output the values using `node.field_program_participants.entity.label`, but it only outputs one value.

[image]

How can I output all the values inside the field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop over the field items:

```
{% for item in node.field_reference %}
  {{ item.entity.label }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this, sorry for my ignorance didn't know that I had to do a loop in order to obtain the values. By the way is there a way I can add comma if there is two or more values?

Comment: you can add a comma with the condition that it is not the last item: `{{ not loop.last ? ', ' }}`

Comment: By the way, how can I output also the URI/URL?

Comment: I don't know which URI/URL you mean, but don't explain here, ask a new question.